# "Notice: Trying to get properties on a non-object" in php Wordpress Select NavMenu

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function, drop-down-menu

I have a Wordpress theme, where I would like to add a dropdown (select) menu in mobile view. I add the code in the header.php, the function.php and the jQuery in my custom.js file.

It works very well (it's linking the url, it's clickable) if a menu exist on my "mainNav" menu section in WordPress.

But if I turned off the menu, I get 2 notifications to the Developer Debug Bar plugin. "Notice: Trying to get properties on a non object" in line 45 and 50.

Here's my code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNqru.png

I think maybe if the navigation menu was empty, the values was empty, or nulled, but i don't know how the hack I correct it. Can anybody help me please? Thank you!

```
//DropDown Select Navigation for the Main Menu
function wp_nav_menu_dropdown( $args = array() ) {
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location' => '',
    'menu_class' => 'mainNav',
);
$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
if ( ( $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $menu_locations[ $args['theme_location'] ] ) ) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_locations[ $args['theme_location'] ] );

    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id );
    ?>
        <select id="menu-<?php echo $args['theme_location'] ?>" class="<?php echo $args['menu_class'] ?>">
            <option value=""><?php _e( 'Navigation Menu' ); ?></option>
            <?php foreach( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $menu_item->url ?>"><?php echo $menu_item->title ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    <?php
}
else {
    ?>
        <select class="menu-not-found">
            <option value=""><?php _e( 'Menu Not Found' ); ?></option>
    </select>
    <?php
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add the menu but you turned it off? I don't understand.

Edit:

After reading your comment I understand your purpose.

According to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_object function `wp_get_nav_menu_object` returns false if there is no menu, so you can run the code if it isn't false.

```
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_locations[ $args['theme_location'] ] );
if($menu !== false) {
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id );
    ?>
        <select id="menu-<?php echo $args['theme_location'] ?>" class="<?php echo $args['menu_class'] ?>">
            <option value=""><?php _e( 'Navigation Menu' ); ?></option>
            <?php foreach( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $menu_item->url ?>"><?php echo $menu_item->title ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: The menu was works well if I or the user turned on, yes! But if the user was turned off this menu, because he/she don't want to use, or install the theme first (when is no active menu) I get “Notice: Trying to get properties on a non-object” message. I am a theme developer so I must to correct this.

Comment: OMG! You are awesome! This helped! Its working and I dont get Notification messages if I dont use a navigation menu. I really thank you! You made my day, because I slowly tore my hair. Thank you Kfinto! Thank you again!